# MySQL MD5 LONGTEXT with Binary Data

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get the md5 hash of a binary value that's stored in a MySQL LONGTEXT field?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  data_path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
  data_column LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (path)
)
```

Then in application code (example PHP):

```
function insert($path) {
  // ...
  $raw_file_data = file_get_contents($path);
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO REGISTRY (data_path, data_column) VALUES (:path, :data)"
  );
  $stmt->bindParam('path', $path);
  $stmt->bindParam('data', $raw_file_data);
  $stmt->execute();
  // ...
}
insert('/path/to/binary_file.jpg');
insert('/path/to/text_file.text');
```

Later, we query the md5 hashes of the inserted rows:

```
SELECT md5(data_column) WHERE data_path = '/path/to/binary_file.jpg';
SELECT md5(data_column) WHERE data_path = '/path/to/text_file.txt';
```

However hashes from MySQL do *not* match the `md5sum` of the actual files for any *non-plaintext* files.

```
md5sum /path/to/binary_file.jpg  # does not match!
md5sum /path/to/text_file.txt    # matches!
```

As far as I understand this has to do with the way MySQL will encode the data for the column's character set.

I also understand this field *should* be a binary field (`BLOB`, `LONGBLOG`, etc.) but this is in a legacy system which uses the same table to store binary and text files and depends on being able to search those text files.

My question is: Is there a way to get the md5 hash of the *binary* value of what is stored in the `data_column`?

Comment: `data_column` is a text column with a collation. You should not store non-plaintext information in there, or you'll risk scrambling your data. Use an actual binary column if you need to store binary files. If you save the data of the jpg back to disk, you will likely not be able to show the jpg image anymore.

Comment: OP seems to agree with you, but this is a legacy system that probably can't be changed, at least not easily.

Comment: Try [casting it to BINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html)?  `SELECT md5(BINARY data_column )`